# Iterate over vector in dictionary

Tags: python, loops, dictionary

I have the following dictionary X:

```
X ={'Deck': [{'geometry': [{'x': 51, 'y': 55},
    {'x': 58, 'y': 47},
    {'x': 25, 'y': 19},
    {'x': 17, 'y': 19},
    {'x': 17, 'y': 27}]}],
 'Superstructure': [{'geometry': [{'x': 52, 'y': 55},
    {'x': 59, 'y': 48},
    {'x': 66, 'y': 54},
    {'x': 60, 'y': 62}]}]}
```

I would like to do the following and print out all the 'x' values for 'Deck' 'Geometry' for example:

```
for row in X.get('Deck','geometry'):
    print(row.get('x'))
```

Clearly this is not working and I'm missing something fundamental.

Comment: Yes, you are missing the fact, that dicts are atomic mappings, while you are trying to access a nested structure. Moreover, the `geometry` key is not even in a second-level dictionary: `X` is a mapping from strings to lists. `[row.get('x') for row in X['Deck'][0]['geometry']]`

Comment: x.get(key1,key2) does not mean you access into key1 then key2. It means if you cannot get the value for key1, then it return you key2 as a result.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This gets all `x` printed for the `Deck`/`geometry`:

```
>>> [i['x'] for i in X['Deck'][0]['geometry']]
[51, 58, 25, 17, 17]
```

You almost got it right, but instead of `X.get('Deck','geometry')` you need to use `X['Deck'][0]['geometry']`, because there's a `list` hidden somewhere in there =)

Comment: Can you explain what is wrong with the way the OP uses 'get()'?

Comment: @quamrana see the answer. there's a `list`, you have to get an element of the list somehow to access the underlying `dict`

Comment: Technically, 
`for row in X.get('Deck')[0].get('geometry'): print(row.get('x'))` would work too, but it's considered more Pythonic and less verbose to use `[]` when one isn't supplying a default value.

Comment: @Graham: Thanks. This is what I was wanting lenik to add to his answer.